# Show planned highways at all zoom levels in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

When zoomed in close enough, Google Maps shows highways that are planned or under construction.

[An example from Cluj, Romania](https://www.google.com/maps/@46.7564201,23.41232,17z) — the grey section of the highway is not built yet and the overlay goes away when you zoom out.

[One more example from Bremmen, Germany](https://www.google.com/maps/@53.097081,8.6906169,17z)

Is there anyway to make this map layer visible at every zoom level?

Comment: Please don't use URL shorteners here. They're used too often to hide inappropriate or restricted content. There's no reason for them.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but have you tried openstreetmap.org to see if they have this data?

Comment: @barrycarter Good idea, no I haven't. Openstreetmap seems to do kind of the same thing but with a larger zoom threshold i.e. planned roads show up from the 1 mile mark down. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Remember, you can use OSM's API to get this data without having to look at a map at all. That's the big advantage to using OSM instead of google maps (in my mind).